# CSS div overlap with a side of vertical centering

Tags: css, html, center, overlap

I am trying to make two overlapping `<div>`s, one of them is the prominent image and it is on top, and the other is more of a background image. But I want the background image to always be centered inside the main image. That is where I start having problems.

```
    ________
   |        |
 __|        |__
|  |        |  |
|  |        |  |
|__|        |__|
   |        |   
   |________|
```

Above is a quick text image of what I want.

edit: it might be important to note that the image on top is an actual `<img>` and the div underneath is an empty `<span>` that I gave width and height to.

Comment: are the images and spans always the same width and height?

Comment: the behind image is, the foreground image is not but it can have a max-width/max-height

Answer (score 0):

You could make a wrapper that would contain both divs. Then center the back image, in the wrapper. After, use z-index to display the other image over top.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I tried that, but I had two spans in my container div and I couldn't get them to overlap without generating white space.

Answer (score 0):

If they are fixed dimensions then you can just set the container to `position:relative;` and it's children to `postion:absolute;` then set the span/image top/left percentages to give the illusion of centralisation.. then `z-index` to insure things layer correctly.

check - http://jsfiddle.net/V4GEy/4/

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, but there is one problem, the image will be fluid so that it does not have a set hieght, is there a way to set the position of the underlying span to 50%?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it. I made a container and set it to position relative then absolute positioned the background span to 50%.

```
#container {
    outline: 2px solid red;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
}

#image {
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: grey;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

#background {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #4B4B4B;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

JsFiddle link::
http://jsfiddle.net/Calebmer/Umx9K/